# How to send String as hexadecimal in python socket?

Tags: python, python-3.x

If I want to use Python to send hexadecimal data to the Java code on the server for parsing, is this the only option:

`b'0x230x230x350x380x390x31'`?

How to send it in a simple form like B `'0x232335383931'`? Because I need to change the numbers frequently, I have tried it by myself, but I can't. Is there any other solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like this is a problem not in Python but with the server you are sending it to: that server is the thing doing the parsing. Here's one way to deal with it:

```py
def prepare(string):
    return b''.join(
        b'0x' + string[i:i + 2]
        for i in range(0, len(string), 2)
    )


print(prepare(b'232335383931'))
```

**Output:**

```
b'0x230x230x350x380x390x31'
```

You can easily edit `b'232335383931'`, then `prepare` it before sending it to your Java server.

Comment: Thanks your answer,but if my string is a variable , just like
`my_str = '232335383931'`
`prepare(b''.join(my_str)) # tips expect byte , string found`

Comment: @gassy either do `my_str = b'232335383931'` OR `prepare(my_str.encode())` (don't do both!)

Comment: hi, but how to get `b'\x23\x23\x35\x38\x39\x31'`   , I used `b'\x' + string[i:i + 2]` , it error, and use `b'\\x' + string[i:i + 2]` , the result  is `b'\\x23\\x23\\x35\\x38\\x39\\x31'` ,